# Server side media recording and broadcasting webRTC

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, webrtc

I have been researching on how to record and save webRTC audio/video sessions from client to server.

I already have a running application which uses C# for APIs along with SignalR for signalling, React JS for Web, React Native for mobile.

Kurento's FAQ page says that we can only use it with JAVA as back-end language, so my question is how can I do server side recording of webRTC session ? I don't want to do client side recording as it is unreliable and can put load client's network/system.

Comment: Ugh it's a horror show but can be done. You need the C++ libraries from Google. The build process itself is a chore. Ultimately though you make your server a participant in the rtc conference and then supply your own video and audio sinks for recording. You're gonna need ffmpeg/libav as well for the recording piece. Be prepared to spend the next several months of your life on this. Or just use the zoom sdk!

Comment: @PeterMoore there really is no other way beside doing it all from scratch?

Comment: Not with a .NET server application, AFAIK. A Node.JS server should have WebRTC built in already - but even then you're still going to need to encode the frames and audio packets to save to disk. I looked into this pretty extensively and couldn't find any pre-existing solutions for .NET server apps.